# My private ethereum block gas limit decrease when mining

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, gas-limit

I set 'genesis.json' like this.

`...
"gasLimit":"0x30479e80",
...`

It's 810,000,000 at decimal.
But when I run the blockchain and start mining,
the block gas limit decrease.

[image]

I'm using 
Geth/v1.9.7-unstable-a73f3f45-20191003/linux-amd64/go1.13.1

I can't find such kind of error examples. Do you know why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the target gas limit in your command starting the geth network

```
--targetgaslimit value    
    Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine (default: 4712388)
```

If you don't do this, each time a block is published, the miner of the block moves the gas limit closer to their defined target gas limit.